# Let's streamline retagging process

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

**Retagging process should be streamlined.**

We need a better way to propose batch operations on tags than what we have now (single thread on meta...). There should be some mechanism to mark a tag as the one to be merged/renamed or deleted. These marks should be visible on tags page so users with privilege to make batch operations could apply them quickly.

We could even try to leverage voting in the process of marking tags. This way if a tag's mark gets X upvotes it could be acted upon.

Comment: Currently (most?) questions about retagging are discussed on questions tagged `[retag-request]`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like this idea at all, and that is even if you made the vote threshold high enough to keep from a few ignorant souls from making potentially disastrous changes to the tag structure.

I would much rather continue to have a thread where this stuff is actually discussed and reasonings given ahead of time then just allowing people to select and vote to merge as they see fit.

Comment: Interesting level of trust for site's members. Did you notice this site is being built by users for users?

Comment: Just because it is built for users and moderated by users does not mean that you let the inmates run every aspect of the asylum.

Comment: By the way, you must have misunderstood my proposal. Batch operations will be performed by the same users as now.

Comment: If you are just wanting items that are voted on to be placed in a queue for the moderators to perform, that makes me feel a little better, but there still doesn't seem to have the proper amount of discussion among the users before hand, unless you plan on having a separate discussion area that goes along with the voting (which is in effect what we already have now).

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully there isn't enough problems with people mis-tagging, or creating poorly thought out tag names for this to too much of an issue.

The way it exists currently, we can discuss it before it actually goes into effect.

Comment: +1 agreed. I don't have a problem with tags getting cleaned up, but to try and implement a mechanism which may may automatically fire after a certain set of votes is asking for trouble. Tag merges and clean ups need to be discussed and find some sort of consensus before taking such an action (especially when you may be messing with hundreds or thousands of posts).

Comment: @TheTXI Please read carefully. Batch operations will be performed by the same users as now.

Comment: Brad - there isn't enough problems with people mis-tagging. You must be kidding. There are plenty of bad tags and each day we have new once created.

Comment: A lot of this would be fixed if there were synonyms for tags.

Comment: Yeah, I know there are a lot of single use tags, thats probably why there are so many questions tagged `[retag-request]`

Answer (score 1):

There may be many retag requests *right now*, but my guess is that the need for batch retagging will greatly decrease after a few weeks.

Comment: Bad guess IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing for the fact that I'm only human (and can only get so much done per day), it *seems* to be broadly workable at the moment...