# SO keeps saying "visit your user page to set your name and email."

Tags: support, notifications, profile-page, login

When I log in to Stack Overflow, the top banner says "Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit your user page to set your name and email." But I have set it, as witnessed by the Autobiographer badge.

Now that I have "registered" here, I get the same thing: "Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! Visit your user page to set your name and email."

Is this normal?

Comment: No, that's not normal. Your username is set and so is your email address (since you don't have an identicon). Please wipe your browser cache, sometimes that solves issues like this.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the **[x]** ?

Comment: Oh my, don't I feel stupid now! That worked.

The thing is, I don't understand /why/ it appears at all. Having clicked the [x] now, I think the site knows I do not want to see it, but still believes I should set my name and e-mail.

Comment: If I'm reading this right I raised a similar issue against StackExchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4365/welcome-banner-for-new-users-still-shown-after-profile-is-visited

Comment: I also had this issue. I didn't realize I had to dismiss the notification even after the issue was resolved.

Comment: I am having this issue.  I agree that it is misleading to merely dismiss it by clicking the [x].  It should detect that the conditions it is checking for are satisfied, assuming it is checking at all.

Comment: so is it a bug or a feature? ;-)