# Didn't get the autobiographer badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, sign-up

The website used to say "Welcome to StackOverflow. Please set the name and email address.". I looked up and found the similar question below.

[SO keeps saying "visit your user page to set your name and email."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40088/so-keeps-saying-visit-your-user-page-to-set-your-name-and-email)

I closed that message. But, I didn't get the 'Autobiographer' badge.

Comment: Website is missing. All fields must be filled.

Comment: Make that an answer @Ladybug so I can upvote it.

Comment: Thanks, @C. Ross, but keep your points. It's a dupe anyway. I'm just too lazy to search for it (like the OP).

Comment: @Ladybug OP is inexperienced, not necessarily lazy.

Comment: @devinb: Too inexperienced to *search*? You are kidding, aren't you?

Comment: @Ladybug As far as the OP knows, this is a site for 'reporting bugs' that *they* experience. Not necessarily that they should be searching for duplicates. Basically: "Since I've never been to this site before, why would the bug that is *specific to me* be here already?" A perfectly reasonable reaction from someone who is *inexperienced* on MSO.

Comment: Ok. Does Gravatar matter in getting badge 'Autobiographer'? The message I was getting was just to set the name and email address. After setting the image, I got the autobiographer badge.

@Ladybug Killer - At that time, I wanted 'Autobiographer' badge on stackoverflow not MSO.

Comment: @Raja: It doesn't matter where you want it. And the website was missing on SO. Now this is filled and you have the badge. Just do what I say.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - I am trying to find the missing piece. I created new account which gave me default values for Email and Real name. The message I am getting again was the message I wrote in my question. Probably, I might have associated this message on my home page with 'Autobiographer' badge(which I know now to completely fill the fields). I might have filled website and Gravatar in order and hence my last comment.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - Sorry. My first comment should have been "Ok. Does Gravatar matter in getting badge 'Autobiographer'? The message I was getting was just to set the name and email address. After setting the image <bold>and website</bold>, I got the autobiographer badge. @Ladybug Killer - At that time, I wanted 'Autobiographer' badge on stackoverflow not MSO." SO and MSO rocks.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of ["Autobiographer" Badge now only requires sharing what YOU want with the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit) - the behaviour described in *this* Q&A has since been changed, as described by the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Compare your profile on Stackoverflow, where you got the badge, with the Meta one... 
missing webpage, location and age  (pretty sure all of them are needed).

BTW, you can easily copy your settings from another site:
go to your profile page you want to change ([meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149061/raja-nakka) I assume), and select the "accounts" tab middle-right of the page. This shows the "Related Accounts" and a button to copy the profile.

Answer (score 4):

Now you [don't need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit) to provide that much info about yourself to get this badge. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get it right away, don't fret! The autobiographer badge is awarded in [batches](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer).